# Code coverage in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I see that the build-in code coverage in Intellij is pretty minimal (only include line coverage, and not branch coverage).

What are the recommended code coverage libraries to work with IntelliJ?

(I used to work with Jacoco in Eclipse).

Comment: so why not keep using that?

Comment: I'm using jacoco-maven-plugin for reporting coverage at release time. During dev, I only monitor what intellij gives. Don't know any plugin for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The IntelliJ IDEA code coverage runner provides **branch** coverage.

> Tracing mode enables accurate collection of the branch coverage, with the ability to track tests, view coverage statistic, and get additional information on each covered line.

(From [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-coverage.html))

To engage this, open the `Edit Run/Debug Configuration` dialog box for your test run and click on the `Code Coverage` tab. Then ...

- Chose coverage runner: `IntelliJ IDEA`
- Click on `Tracing` (instead of the default: `Sampling`)

Run your test and then click into the class from the Coverage Window and you'll see branch information in the side bar.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: But how to summarize total branch coverage percentage? Just like in Eclipse with jacoco?

Comment: There's an open issue against IntelliJ for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102075

Comment: According to [JetBrains tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102075) summarizng total branch coverage percentage was delivered in `2018.2 (182.3684.101)`